# How to find $\delta$ in the $\varepsilon-\delta$ definition of continuity

Tags: continuity, numerical-methods, epsilon-delta

We knew the $\varepsilon-\delta$ definition for continuous function: a function $f$ is continuous at $x_0$ iff for all $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $|f(x) - f(x_0)| < \varepsilon$ whenever $|x - x_0| < \delta$.

My question:

> Let $f$ be continuous on some interval $[a, b]$ and $x_0 \in (a, b)$. With a given $\varepsilon$, how can we find $\delta$ such that $$|f(x) - f(x_0)| < \varepsilon \quad \text{ whenever } \quad |x - x_0| < \delta?$$

I think it is really difficult to have a "theoretical" answer, but I wonder if we have any numerical method to find $\delta$:

**INPUT:** function $f$, $x_0$ and $\varepsilon$.

**OUTPUT:** $\delta$.

Thank you very much.

Comment: If your function $f$ is suitable as input for a computer program, you can write down/analyse its AST and combine the Lipschitz constants of the involved elementary operations and functions. This is similar to automatic differentiation.

Comment: @LutzL. I don't understand your comment. How would you handle $f(x)=x\sin (1/x)$ for $x\ne 0,$  and $f(0)=0,$ when $x_0=0$?

Comment: @DanielWainfleet : I should have said that this covers most "normal" situations. Singularities in intermediate steps that vanish in the final result, also cases like $\sqrt{|x|}$, are not covered under that general approach. But in general, the functions that are representable by computer programs are smooth almost everywhere. BTW, can you give a computer program that reliably evaluates that function for $|x|<10^{-8}$?

Comment: @LutzL. I have no special expertise in programming. If I wanted to find one I might look on the programming site(s) on the Exchange. For accurate proportional values there are obvious difficulties.